# How is $\mathbb E[ \int_0^T H_s^2 \mathrm d s] < \infty$ important for this claim?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm reading about Ito’s stochastic integral at page 35 of this [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc1_final.pdf).

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Let $H=(H_t, t\ge 0)$ be a stochastic process with continuous trajectories. Fix $T>0$ such that $\mathbb E[ \int_0^T H_s^2 \mathrm d s] < \infty$. For $n \ge 1$, we define
$$
H_{s,n} := \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} H\left(\frac{(i-1) T}{2^n}\right) 1_{ \left (\frac{(i-1) T}{2^n}, \frac{i T}{2^n} \right]}(s) \quad \forall s \in [0, T].
$$

Then for $(\omega, n) \in \Omega \times \mathbb N$, the map $s \mapsto H_{s, n} (\omega)$ is a step function. Because $H$ has continuous trajectories, we have
$$
H_{s, n} (\omega) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}  H_{s} (\omega) \quad \forall (\omega, s) \in \Omega \times [0, T].
$$

---

The author then said that

> $$
> \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^T (H_{s,n}-H_s)^2 \mathrm d s\bigg] \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.
> $$

Could you elaborate on how to use $\mathbb E[ \int_0^T H_s^2 \mathrm d s] < \infty$ to fix my below failed attempt?

---

**Proof**

- Fix $\omega \in \Omega$. We define $f_n:[0, T] \to \mathbb R$ by $f_n (s) := H_{s,n} (\omega)$. We define $f:[0, T] \to \mathbb R$ by $f (s) := H_{s} (\omega)$. Then $\sup_n \|f_n\|_\infty  \le \|f\|_\infty < \infty$. Also, $f_n-f$ converges to $0$ pointwise. By dominated convergence theorem, we have
  $$
  \int_0^T (f_n-f)^2 \mathrm d s \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.
  $$
- We define $Y_n:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ by
  $$
  Y_n (\omega) := \int_0^T (H_{s,n} (\omega)-H_s(\omega))^2 \mathrm d s.
  $$
  As proved above, $Y_n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ almost surely.

Comment: You have proven pointwise convergence of $Y_n$ to $0$. You need to prove $L_1$ convergence of $Y_n$ to $0$. For this you may use $\mathbb E[\int_0^T H_s^2ds]<\infty$

Comment: @fKonrad I don't get your ideas. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Almost sure convergence means $Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow 0$ for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$; $L^1$ convergence means $\mathbb{E}[|Y_n(\omega)|] \rightarrow 0$. They are not the same and don't imply each other.

Comment: @snar I agree. Could you elaborate on how to prove the claim?

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439649/how-is-mathbb-e-int-0t-h-s2-mathrm-d-s-infty-important-for-this-clai)...